# Jquery Autocomplete not populating after error thrown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am running a ASP.Net MVC application and using jQuery's Autocomplete in one of the textboxes to populate contract numbers after the 6th digit/character.

It is working flawlessly, until after an error is thrown for a validation check.

My code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ContractNumber").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetContractId")',
            open: function () { $('ul.ui-autocomplete').hide().fadeIn() },
            close: function () { $('ul.ui-autocomplete').show().fadeOut() },
            minLength:6
        });
});
```

The code that redirects to the correct controller to get the contract number is here:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('body').on('focus', "#ContractNumber", function () {
          $("#ContractNumber").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/PurchaseRequestDetail/GetContractId",
                    minLength: 1,
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };;
                        }))
                    }
                })
            }
          });
```

Here is the autocomplete that is working fine, before the error:

[image]

I wanted this autocomplete to work, on focus of the textbox, whether a validation error thrown or not.

validation error: [image]

The code that checks for ModelState if contract number is not found :

```
if (contractNo is null)
                {
                    // row.ContractId = foundList.ContractId;
                    db.PurchaseRequestDetail.Add(newRow);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
else if (contractNo != null)
                {
                    if (foundList is null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("ContractNumber", "Contract Number not in the database.");

                        // reload the drop down lists, they don't survive the trip to the server and back
                        viewModel.ContractList = GetContractList(viewModel.ContractId);

                        return View("CreateEdit", viewModel);
                    }
                }
```

Any pointers in correcting this would be helpful.

TIA.

Comment: Can you also show the validation error that you are getting. It might give further clarity.

Comment: updated the post with validation error, pls check @mukhtar alam

Comment: Thanks for showing the validation error, can you also show the code that generates it?

Comment: @Kinglish, updated the post with the code for modelstate

Comment: hmmm, I really don't know. Of course it seems that the modelstate error is disabling the input autocomplete element. I would consider another way of displaying the error message in a way that does not interrupt the form element.

Comment: Might be missing the actual ask here. If so I apologize, but autocomplete will only match data that's there. Do you have anything that matches "daca95"? If not, I would expect nothing available via autocomplete.

Comment: @jslowik , i tried with existing / matching contract numbers and autocomplete is not kickingoff after any validation error

Comment: @Kinglish, that's why i am rebinding the list with viewmodel.Contractlist